# Broken range/len use

Tags: python, range

Assume that the function being called within the function is working correctly (it is). What am I doing wrong here?

```
def board_contains_word_in_column(board, word):
    """ (list of list of str, str) -> bool

    Return True if and only if one or more of the columns of the board
    contains word.


    Precondition: board has at least one row and one column, and word is a
    valid word.

    >>> board_contains_word_in_column([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 'NO')
    False
    """


    for char in range(len(board)):
        if word in make_str_from_column(board,char):
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Sorry- I'm fairly new to python. What's wrong here?

Comment: your code should be indented from the level of indentation of `def`

Comment: Ah it is in IDLE- messed up the copypaste. Thanks for pointing that out for future relevance.

Comment: But please fix the pasted code (there is an edit button under the question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`len(board)` is 2. I suspect you mean `len(board[0])` which is 4

Here is a hint for an easier way to write your function

```
>>> board = [['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']]
>>> tuple('NO') in zip(*board)
False
>>> tuple('NS') in zip(*board)
True
```